# Java - Invalid stream header

Tags: java, serialization, tcp, network-programming, objectoutputstream

I am working on some networking with Java and I am having an issue with converting an object to a byte array, splitting that array into 2 parts, sending each over a TCP stream, receiving it, reconstructing the byte array, and then reforming the object.

So far it is all working. I have it all except for the reconstruction of the object. I get this error when using a ObjectInputStream:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 34323435
```

Which is a common error I see online. I have tried fixing it. One of the causes I've heard of is that the stream was not flushed after sending the bytes, but my code does flus the steam before sending it. My code to send the data is:

```
 public void sendTcp(ObjectOutputStream tcpOut) {
    try {
        synchronized(tcpOut) {
            tcpOut.write(data);
            tcpOut.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I am able to successfully read those bytes on the server side. The problem comes when combining the bytes back together. Once that is done I use this to recreate the object:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
Object object = is.readObject();
is.close();
in.close();
```

But the error gets thrown on the ObjectInputStream line. I have also looked at the raw data by debugging and it all matches up. The bytes of the object, before it was split and sent, matches the bytes that were recombined after it was received. I've been stuck on this for a little while and it would be very helpful if someone could help.

Comment: Are you able to construct the Object at Client side using the same bytes?

Comment: I have tried that yet but what I am doing is first I create a new ByteArrayOutputSteam, then create a new ObjectOutputStream, and then I write the object and get the bytes of the object. Then I flush and close those streams. Then I take that array and I split it into parts and then send each array over an ObjectOutputStream attached to the Socket output stream (there is only one object output stream for the socket. I don't recreate it). Then I receive it on the server side and put the arrays together.

Comment: Then I take that single array and send it to a new ByteArrayInputStream and then that to a new ObjectInputStream. Then I use that to get the object but it throws that error when creating the ObjectInputStream

Answer (score 3):

> I am having an issue with converting an object to a byte array, splitting that array into 2 parts, sending each over a TCP stream, receiving it, reconstructing the byte array, and then reforming the object.

Of course you are. It's pointless. There's too much fluffing around here. You're over-complicating it and making mistakes in the process. You don't need any of this. It's just a waste of time and space. TCP already does splitting into segments; IP already does splitting into packets, and routers already do splitting into fragments. You don't need to add another layer of that.

- Get rid of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream`
- Create one `ObjectOutputStream` and one `ObjectInputStream,` in that order, wrapped around the socket output and input streams respectively, at both ends, and keep them for the life of the socket
- use `writeObject()` and `readObject()` directly on these object streams
- don't use any other streams or readers or writers on the same socket.

Comment: That's not what Im looking for. And I dont think you understand what I mean by splitting. When sending bytes over a stream you are limited to the amount you can send, I think it's around 64k. So what happens when you have 200k bytes? By splitting it I can send them over and recreate them. This is commonly called packet streaming. Anyways I found out that my problem was I was not removing some bytes from the beginning that I inserted and forgot to remove. So everything I had technically worked fine.

Comment: When you've tried this and it doesn't work, let me know. I won't be holding my breath. At present your are just guessing, and you are mistaken. Clearly you have not tried what is recommended here. When sending bytes over a stream you are not limited by anything, let alone 64k. When you have 200k bytes, just send them. Any 'packet streaming' required is already done by TCP and IP, as mentioned above. No further user intervention is required. Your question and comment don't make sense.